# Android UI Design - expandable/collapsible view (column view that expands left/right)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-view

I'm thinking of having a screen that divided by 5 (number is configurable) columns which takes up from the very top to the bottom of the screen, like the vertical blinds of the window.

And each of them is focusable, when focused, it will expand either left/right, when another one is focused, it will collapse and the new one will expand. There also will be some nice animation between.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I'm totally new to Android UI part. Like what kind of view I should use, how to have them configurable?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head you can simply have a linear layout with 5 children ViewGroup layouts inside it .. in your xml add animatelayout changes on those children to get some slick animation.

Now inside those child layouts you will have a layout that is the expandable size of that layout and then set its visibility to gone.

on click you set its visibility to visible.. keep track of it so you can collapse it when another is selected.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for helping! I'm thinking of have a 2d grid view of images that user can select in each of the column when it's expanded, and when user scroll left/right, the selected images need to be kept. Is there anything I need to keep an eye on so that I won't lose data during scrolling? Can I still use the views you described above? Thanks!

Comment: nothing you need to keep track of you can use the way.. just make sure if the list is going to be more than 5 or 10 columns then probably re-think it and make it a recyclerview that scrolls horizontally maybe... mark as answer if you think this was helpful :)